# Roundup to next value in series

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to round up the result of a calculation to the next largst value in a series stored in an array.
I've tried the following but a calculation of 10.3 is rounding down to 10 when I want it to roundup to the next value in series of 16. When $s = 14.9 it works.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$s = 10.3

// List of standard cable CSA
$csa = array(1,1.5,2.5,4,6,10,16,25,35,50,70,95,120,150,185,240,300,400);
function nextSizeUp($s, $csa) {
    $closest = null;
    foreach ($csa as $size) {
        if ($closest === null || abs($s - $closest) > abs($size - $s)) {
            $closest = $size;
        }
    }
    return $closest;
}
echo nextSizeUp($s,$csa);
```

Comment: Replace your if statement inside the for loop with this - 
`if ($size > $s) { $closest = $size; break; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to round up, not find the closest value. Something like this:

```
$s = 10.3;

// List of standard cable CSA
$csa = array(1,1.5,2.5,4,6,10,16,25,35,50,70,95,120,150,185,240,300,400);

function nextSizeUp($s, $csa) 
{
    foreach ($csa as $size) {
        if ($size >= $s) {
            return $size;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

echo nextSizeUp($s,$csa);
```

This returns `16` and `false` when the value is bigger than 400.